# What is subplot_adjust() doing to pyplot axes?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot several subplots in a `pyplot` figure, one of which has two subplots. I handle this by creating one extra `pyplot.ax` based on the location of the bottom one.

Now, a problem arise when I adjust axes 1 through 4 using `fig.subplots_adjust()`, in order to leave an extra space on the right for legend. On the picture below, you can see that although my two datasets are the same length, the bar plot stretches further to the right.

I would like to apply the same adjustment to `ax5` as I do to the other four axes when using `fig.subplot_adjust()`, but I cannot figure out what this method is doing with the 
`matplotlib.axes.Axes` instance.

Looking at the documentation, I could not find a method that suits my purpose:
http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes

So what is `fig.subplot_adjust()` doing to my axes? How can I reproduce this behavior so that ALL axes align?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig, ( ax1, ax2, ax3 , ax4) = plt.subplots( figsize=(18.0, 11.0) , nrows=4, ncols=1) 

## some fake stand-alone data
days = 365 * 5
dates = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta( day - 1) for day in range(days)]
data_series = np.random.rand( days )
data_series2 = [np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi / 365 ) + np.random.rand(1) * 0.1 for x in range( days ) ]

######  Plots made up temperatures 
ax4.set_frame_on(False)
ax4.plot_date( dates , data_series2 , color="black", ls="solid", lw=2, ms=0 )

# Now on the same plot try to add som precipitation as a plot
ax5 = fig.add_axes(ax4.get_position() , frameon=True, zorder = -10.0)
ax5.bar( dates, data_series, edgecolor="blue", zorder = -10.0 )
ax5.xaxis_date()

# gets rid of bar-plot labels
ax5.set_xticks([]); ax5.set_yticks([])

fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8) # <- Pandora's box
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you making two axes over the same real estate (ax4 and ax5)?  You can put multiple plots on the same axes...

Comment: Thanks @Ajean, would I be able to plot it with different y-axes then? in this very case, I want temperatures and precipitations on the same subplot, the data have different order of magnitude, and I would like the bars' zero to be on bottom while the plot would vary around it. If you think I can do that on the same ax, I am willing to look into it.

Comment: I see you already have an answer, but another way to go which will also suit your needs answers your last question, which is yes, you can plot with different y-axes. See the tutorial about twinned axes [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).

Comment: @Ajean , I finally opted for your suggested solution, which is more concise and more elegant that what I tried to do. Data_addict was good at explaining the malfunction in the example though. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that ax5 is not in a subplot.

```
fig.get_axes()

[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x220175c0>,
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x18d48240>,
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1c5f3630>,
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1a430710>,
<matplotlib.axes._axes.Axes at 0x1c4defd0>] # There is ax5 and it is not under _subplots
```

so when you do

```
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
```

you adjust the subplot and not the axe directly so you don't affect ax5.

An easy way to correct than is to adjust ax4 before calling ax5, so ax5 will have the same proportion than ax4.

By calling

```
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
```

before

```
ax5 = fig.add_axes(ax4.get_position() , frameon=True, zorder = -10.0)
```

you will get the proper output.

So your code just have to look like that;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

fig, ( ax1, ax2, ax3 , ax4) = plt.subplots( figsize=(18.0, 11.0) , nrows=4, ncols=1) 

## some fake stand-alone data
days = 365 * 5
dates = [datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta( day - 1) for day in range(days)]
data_series = np.random.rand( days )
data_series2 = [np.sin(x * 2 * np.pi / 365 ) + np.random.rand(1) * 0.1 for x in range( days ) ]

######  Plots made up temperatures 
ax4.set_frame_on(False)
ax4.plot_date( dates , data_series2 , color="black", ls="solid", lw=2, ms=0 )

# I move the subplot_adjust here before you create ax5
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8) 

# Now on the same plot try to add som precipitation as a plot
ax5 = fig.add_axes(ax4.get_position() , frameon=True, zorder = -10.0)
ax5.bar( dates, data_series, edgecolor="blue", zorder = -10.0 )
ax5.xaxis_date()

# gets rid of bar-plot labels
ax5.set_xticks([]); ax5.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```